# cross-referencing cloudformation not working

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have created a policy template and outputted the ARN:

```
Resources:

   # Codebuild Policies
   CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1:
     Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
     Properties: 
       Description: 'This service role enables AWS CodePipeline to interact with other AWS services, including AWS CodeBuild, on your behalf'
       Path: "/"
       PolicyDocument: 
         Version: "2012-10-17"
         Statement: 
           - Resource: "*"
             Effect: "Allow"
             Action:
...

Outputs:

   StackName:
   Value: !Ref AWS::StackName

   CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy:
     Description: The ARN of the ManagedPolicy1
     Value: !Ref CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1
     Export:
       Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1'
```

Now I want o import these Policy into a template with Roles and

```
# Codebuilding  service role
CodeBuildRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CodeBuildRole
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Action: ["sts:AssumeRole"]
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: [codebuild.amazonaws.com]
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Path: / 
    Policies:
    - PolicyDocument:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1'
```

But this fails. I'm getting an error, what is wrong?

merci in advance

A

Comment: What is the error? You get an error-message, or just some buggy behavior is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reference the Managed Policy you created with your first stack, using the !Ref function?

The CF for the policy:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties: 
    Path: "/"
    PolicyDocument: 
    ...
    Outputs:
      CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy:
        Value: !Ref CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy1.Arn
```

The CF for the role:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  PolicyName: 
    Type: String
  Resources: 
    CodeBuildRole: 
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties: 
        Path: "/"
        Policies: !Ref PolicyName
```

Also checkout the docs for [Cloudformation IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-templateexamples) an [CloudFormation Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html)

Comment: Merci for the comment. The answer was quite simple at th end: you can’t use ref with the Policies: Popty, one need to use ManagedPolicies. There you can use fn::ImportValue and import the Value exported from the other template.

Comment: @aerioeus consider writing an answer instead of only a comment with your solution. This is more clear for others and also can get upvotes to increase your reputation here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the AWS resource Type: `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` instead of `AWS::IAM::Policy` . 
If you use `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` you can export the policy ARN like this

```
 CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy:
   Description: ARN of the managed policy
   Value: !Ref CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy
```

and import it into another template with `fn::ImportValue` or `fn::GetAtt`
Using `AWS::IAM::Policy` only allows to create **inline policies** which *cannot be referenced*.